# python selenium function error

Tags: python, selenium

im trying to make this playlist webscraper in python, im having some problems. the code runs fine! but about 4 songs in on the 5th song i get an error, i've tried exception handling, if statements but nothing works, help!

```
    # coding=utf-8

from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://convert2mp3.net/en/index.php')

#########################################################

my_url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=afUx6AIG3Tg&list=RDEMk8jQ6KI-B3A3H0tMKkdgRQ'

uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

# Cleaning up the HTML
page_soup = soup(page_html, 'html.parser')

# Grabs each product!
containers = page_soup.findAll('li', {'class': 'yt-uix-scroller-scroll-unit'})

for container in containers:
    title = container.a.h4.string
    link = container.a['href']
    href = 'https://youtube.com/' + link
    # print(title)
    # print(href)

    driver.get("http://convert2mp3.net/en/index.php")
    urlEntry = driver.find_element_by_id('urlinput')
    urlEntry.send_keys(href)
    urlEntry.submit()

    continueButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""/html/body/div[3]/div/div[1]/form/div[5]/div/button""")
    continueButton.click()

    # backButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""/html/body/div[3]/div/div[1]/a""")
    # backButton.click()

    downloadButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""/html/body/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/a[1]""")
    downloadButton.click()

    # backButton = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.NoSuchElementException(()))



# driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="convertForm"]/fieldset/button""").click()

# This sets up the soup and extracts the data from the url!

# This sets up the broswer and opens it to the designated webpage!
# driver = webdriver.Chrome()
# driver.get('http://convert2mp3.net/en/index.php')
# urlEntry = driver.find_element_by_id('urlinput')
# urlEntry.send_keys(href)
# urlEntry.submit()
```

i tried using, `backButton = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.NoSuchElementException(())`)

but that didnt work, im lost, i dont understand how to make the computer wait until the error pops up, i can probably say to wait until the 5th song, but what if the same thing happens to certain links, then the issue needs to be handled everytime that happens

Comment: Which error are you seeing on `backButton = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.NoSuchElementException(()))` line?

Comment: @DebanjanB  get the same error, selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException, if you run the code without that line, you will see, it will download everything, then the 5th song ill get an error, i want to make it so that it isn't an error, so that the computer knows that, that situation (url can't be converted) is going to happen so that it knows, instead of pressing continue, it has to press back and input a new url. if you run the code you, you'll see what i mean